# Is it useful to log an object hashcode?

Tags: java, logging, tostring, hashcode

I see a lot of the following line in projects I took over:

```
log.debug(submitObject(" + object + ")");
log.debug(registerUser(" + user + ")");
```

and so on.

In the logs this prints out something like:

```
SubmitObject(java.lang.Object@13a317a)
```

Is it useful to log just the object type and its hashcode? Say I want to know the name of the user object but I only have the hashcode, would it be possible for me to reconstruct the object based on the hashcode?

From the javadoc for object.toString()

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.  The toString method for class Object
>   returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
>   object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned
>   hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other
>   words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
>   Returns: a string representation of the object.

I myself always override the toString() of a custom object so it prints out all the fields of the object. Should I start printing the object code instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, keep overriding toString() which is much more useful. The default toString() is practically useless except that it at least shows what the class instance is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use  `ReflectionToStringBuilder` from `org.apache.commons`, if you do not have access to source code, or if you do not want implement toString for change existing code.

For Example:

`if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {`

```
  LOGGER.debug("User : "
    + reflectionToStringBuilder.toString(user ,
         ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE))
```

}

`"LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()` is very important as `toString` Operation, or reflectionToStringBuilder, will be executed before calling log.debug, so you do not want such expensive operations.

`ReflectionToStringBuilder`JavaDoc: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html

Answer (score 1):

That hash code is a randomly assigned value.  It is only useful if you want to check you had the same object in a previous log, or a different one (i.e. very rarely)

Comment: I have found it **very** useful to print the hash codes in log when investigating connection leaks. It helped me track the `Connection` objects traveling in and out of a pool, and find out where a connection has traveled out and did not return to the pool (a leak). Without the ability to print the object hash codes, this task would have been more difficult for me.